# encfs automount and authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, automounting, encfs

Here's my problem: I have encfs configured in such a way that on login the subfolder `./private` is mounted. However, when I use the workstation remotely via ssh, I don't give my password on login, because I connect from a trusted laptop whose public key is in the file `authorized_keys`.

Accordingly, the subfolder `./private` doesn't get mounted. I need to do `su myself` and give my password. After that `./private` gets automounted.

Is there a way around it? I.e. I would like not to give my password when I connect via ssh, and at the same time I would like `./private` to be mounted on ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround.

In order to mount the encfs filesystem, the server has to get ahold of your password *somehow*. If you don't supply your password, there's no way the filesystem can be mounted!